# Pub/Sub to Datastore Batch Dataflow Job in Apache Beam Python SDK Possible?

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

I have a Pub/Sub topic which will periodically (usually once every few days or weeks, but sometimes more often) receive batches of messages. I'd like to kick off a batch Dataflow job to read these messages, perform some transformations, write the result to Datastore, then stop running. When a new batch of messages goes out, I want to kick off a new job. I've read over the Apache Beam Python SDK docs and many SO questions, but am still uncertain about a few things.

Can Pub/Sub IO read as part of a non-streaming job? Can the same job then write using Datastore IO (which doesn't currently support streaming)? Can I assume the default global window and trigger will correctly tell the job when to stop reading from Pub/Sub (when the batch of messages is no longer being written)? Or do I need to add some sort of trigger/windowing scheme like max time or max number of elements? Would that trigger, when triggered, tell the global window to close and therefore end the job?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Incorrectly answered assuming this was for Java Beam with Dataflow.

Apologies, I missed that this was for Python.

Per the documentation [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/) added in [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/7758), Datastore is explicitly not supported in streaming mode in Python. There is an inconsistency in the documentation, where it claims that Python batch mode for Pub/Sub is supported, whereas the [linked code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py) says that it is only supported in streaming pipelines.  I have filed a [Jira bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-7136) to try to get this resolved.

This appears to not be a currently supported use case for Dataflow in python streaming mode. I would suggest that you consider using the Java version of Apache Beam instead, which [supports streaming writes into Datastore](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0c46d2e40dca8fccb49c018d8649120dbe569930/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/datastore/DatastoreV1.java#L107).

Comment: I've tried `beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(2 * 60))` and `beam.WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows(), trigger=AfterProcessingTime(60 * 2), accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)`, but neither seem to allow this to write to Datastore. Right after I call the window/trigger, I have a function to turn Pub/Sub msg into an Entity protobuf, and I can see the Entity is correctly created with all original properties. However when I change a property on the Entity, that new value is not written to Datastore. I've verified the key ID, namespace, and kind are all correct.